# Choropleth map not coloring countries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, choropleth

I asked a question yesteday, but i guess it was a bit too much code or unclear, so i've deleted it and will try to make my question more clear.

I have a dataframe (df) with all the countries in the world, it looks like this :

```
Country CountryCode Population
0   Afghanistan AF  30206627.0
1   Åland Islands   AX  NaN
2   Albania AL  2881160.0
3   Algeria DZ  37812804.0
4   American Samoa  AS  NaN
```

My choropleth code looks like this:

```
data = dict(type = 'choropleth', 
           locations = df['CountryCode'],
           z = df['Population'],
           text = df['Country'],
           colorbar = dict(title = 'Population'))

layout = dict(title = '2013 global Population', 
             geo = dict(showframe = False,
                       projection = {'type': 'stereographic'}))

choromap = go.Figure(data = [data], layout = layout)

plot(choromap)
```

When i run my code i get the following result:

[image: Map]

As you can see my population bar is colored correctly, and it takes the correct population values from the dataframe and puts them on the population bar.
So what am i doing wrong here, since i just gives me a blank map, instead of coloring the different countries?

Thank you in advance
Best regards .

Comment: Is it because i am using 2 digit country-codes instead of 3 digits?
(ISO Alpha2 vs ISO alpha3?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out, after exporting my choropleth map to Ploty, that the problem is indeed i am using ISO-2 instead of ISO-3, so i guess i'll have to find a way to convert the codes.